# Algebras of observables in classical physics. Are C*-algebras useful?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, observables

When studying the algebraic formulation of Quantum Mechanics, C*-algebras are a very useful tool for dealing with algebras of observables. I have been studying whether all classical systems in physics could be modelled by C*-algebras (specifically, their observables), particularly commutative ones. However, I am not sure if this is possible or interesting in any way. Can it be said that the observables of a classical system have the same structure as the elements of the Hermitian part of a commutative C*-algebra? Is that correct?

Does anyone know of any references or bibliography that deal with this topic? Thank you.